# How to capture optional parameters from uri via regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, logging, nginx

The following method parses a line from nginx log:

```
def test_parse_line2(self):
    groups = ['ip', 'timestamp', 'offset', 'command', 'path', 'protocol', 'status', 'bytes', 'client']
    line = '1.2.3.4 - - [22/Oct/2015:12:01:49 -0500] "GET /mypath/?param1=value1&param2=value2 HTTP/1.1" 200 51 "-" "SomeRandomClient"'
    pattern = r'(?P<ip>[^ ]+) - - \[(?P<timestamp>[^ ]+) (?P<offset>[-\+][0-9]{4})] "' +\
        r'(?P<command>[A-Z]+) /(?P<path>[^ ]+) (?P<protocol>[^"]+)" (?P<status>[0-9]+) (?P<bytes>[0-9]+) (?:[^ ]+)'+\
        r' "(?P<client>[^"]+)'
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    if match:
        for group_name in groups:
            print(group_name, match.group(group_name))
```

Is there a way to modify it, so that I separately capture the mandatory path, `mypath`, and optional parameters, `param1=value1&param2=value2`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the path's pattern matcher by two distinct matcher : `(?P<mypath>[^?]+)\?(?P<myargs>[^ ]+)`

Comment: Worked after I replaced \? with \??